# TextView borderColor Not Changing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, border, uicolor

I am trying to change the borderColor of a textView in Swift. If I set it using a preset color it works fine:

```
inView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
```

However, when I try to set it to a custom RGB value, the borderColor does not change:

```
inView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 100, green: 230, blue: 100, alpha: 1).cgColor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct color properly (`$value/255.0`) as color range is from 0 to 1 ( aka `0 to 255/255` )

```
inView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 100/255.0, green: 230/255.0, blue: 100/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
```